# How can this count return 0 if no row match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the following query to return 0 if there is no match:

```
CREATE TABLE #Operations (
    Discriminator varchar(40)
);

INSERT INTO #Operations
VALUES
    ('HistoricoCarga'),
    ('HistoricoDescarga')
;

SELECT
    o.Discriminator,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(*)
    END AS Total
FROM 
    HistoricosOperacion ho
        RIGHT JOIN #Operations o
            ON ho.Discriminator = o.Discriminator
WHERE
    ho.FechaEnvioIntegracionUTC IS NULL
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ho.FechaUTC, GETUTCDATE()) > 10
GROUP BY o.Discriminator;
```

I've tried changing the `count(*)` to `count(ho.Discriminator)` or changing the temp table to:

```
CREATE TABLE #Operations (
    Discriminator varchar(40),
    dummy int
);

INSERT INTO #Operations
VALUES
    ('HistoricoCarga', 0),
    ...
```

I need the output to be as follows:

```
HistoricoCarga         0
HistoricoDescarga      0
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` never returns null, it may return `0`

Comment: @charlieface Correct. There is no need to use the ```CASE``` statement there. Thanks for pointing that out, it was part of my trial and error

Comment: This expression `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ho.FechaUTC, GETUTCDATE())` is very infefficient. Applying a function against a column is generally NOT a good idea as it will prevent the optimizer from using any useful indexes with that column. In addition, you defeated your RIGHT JOIN by referring to columns in the unpreserved (HistoricosOperacion ho) table. That implicitly converts the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't COUNT(*), count the join column from the sparse side of the join

```
CREATE TABLE #Operations (
    Discriminator varchar(40)
);

INSERT INTO #Operations
VALUES
    ('HistoricoCarga'),
    ('HistoricoDescarga')
;

SELECT
    o.Discriminator,
    COUNT(ho.Discriminator) AS Total
FROM 
    
    #Operations o
    LEFT JOIN
    HistoricosOperacion ho
    ON ho.Discriminator = o.Discriminator AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ho.FechaUTC, GETUTCDATE()) > 10

GROUP BY o.Discriminator;
```

Moving the restriction out of the WHERE and into the ON means that only rows where both things are true will join. You could also consider :

```
#Operations o
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM HistoricosOperacion WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ho.FechaUTC, GETUTCDATE()) > 10) ho
ON ho.Discriminator = o.Discriminator
```

if it makes more sense to you